# Radiobutton check on user interaction

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity, radio-button

I am developing a quiz activity based on football formations. I show a list of radio buttons to the user asking him to select the on with the current 'role' in the formation.  What I am trying to develop here is based on the user click on a radio button to check if the correct radio button was pressed. In other words I have a list of radio buttons in my XML and based on the question I want the user to click on the specific radio button in order to proceed to the next question. As long as the user clicks on wrong radio buttons, a message is shown as a Toast message saying that the radio button pressed is incorrect, and the tries left. the maximum tries per question is set to 5. This all need to be done without the click of a button. The code is below; if not the right implementation was used in such case (or any recommendations)  please let me know

```
public void run(){
            int userTries = 0;
            while(userTries < 5){

            if(leftBack.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(FootballFindThePosition.this,
                            "Well Done! \nMoving on!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    userTries = 0;
                }
                else if(rightBack.isChecked() || cbleft.isChecked() || cbright.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(FootballFindThePosition.this,
                            "Please try again!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    userTries++;
                }

            }
        }
```

The radiobuttons does not belong to a radiogroup (not sure if thats okay)

Comment: Well, if you use a radiogroup, you can use that to find which button is selected and compare it to the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really want something like this rather than a running thread.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html

In other words a common method declared in your xml and implemented in your activitity that listens to the individual clicks.